# Stripe Checkout: Cross Sells Success URL

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working with [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) and [Cross Sells](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/cross-sells). You can view my success and cancel urls below. **My question:** Is it possible to have an additional success_url if the user adds an additional product at checkout? I need to send a different success email if the client adds a product via Cross sell.

success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/dashboard?success=true`,

cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/dashboard?canceled=true`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can only set one `success_url` for a Checkout Session.

Upon checkout completion (i.e., by listening to the `checkout.session.complete` webhook event), you can [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve#retrieve_checkout_session) the Checkout Session object and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects#expanding_objects) its [line_items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) to view the list of line items that purchased by the customer. This list would also include the additional cross-sell items if available.